# swift: load specific data based on indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-instruction

**Problem:**

I want to use a single viewcontroller to load data, specifically text and images, according to the `indexPath.row` of my tableview. All cells are segued to the one viewcontroller. I am loading the labels and images from arrays.

When the tableview loads it crashes and I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on this line `headerTitle.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]`

**Code:**

This controller is used for the tableview and viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CCArtController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var headerTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var centerImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UITextView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var cellContent = [/*0*/"Arroyo", /*1*/"Buddy Rogers", /*2*/"Chopsticks", /*3*/"Colorful Fountain", /*4*/"Diamond", /*5*/"Dinah Shore Bridge Mosaics", /*6*/"Fountain of Life", /*7*/"Fountains", /*8*/"Historic Photo Collection", /*9*/"Holistic 77-A", /*10*/"Hollywood Heroes", /*11*/"Indian Gathering", /*12*/"Indian Women", /*13*/"Mountain Cathedrals", /*14*/"Old Firehouse", /*15*/"Perfect Union", /*16*/"Pickford Lizards", /*17*/"Saguaro and Barrell Cactus", /*18*/"Swiss Cheese", /*19*/"The New Beginning", /*20*/"Thunderbolt", /*21*/"Tic Toc", /*22*/"Wheel of Time", /*23*/"Arte Vita Gallery", /*24*/"Coachella Valley Art Scene", /*25*/"Colin Fisher Studios", /*26*/"Gary's Creative Warehouse", /*27*/"Leslie Jean Porter Gallery", /*28*/"Rebecca Fine Art Gallery", /*29*/"Adobe House", /*30*/"El Gallito Restaurant", /*31*/"The Agnes Pelton Home", /*32*/"The Val Samuelson Home", /*33*/"Willard Price House", /*34*/"Cathedral City Dog Park", /*35*/"Century Park", /*36*/"Dennis Keat Soccer Park", /*37*/"Memorial Park", /*38*/"Ocotillo Park", /*39*/"Panorama Park", /*40*/"Patriot Park", /*41*/"Town Square Park", /*42*/"2nd Street Park"]

var cellDetail = [/*0*/"City Hall First Floor Lobby", /*1*/"Town Square - Civic Center", /*2*/"Da Val Dr at Ramon Rd", /*3*/"Cathedral City Branch Library", /*4*/"Patriot Park at Big League Dreams", /*5*/"Dinah Shore Bridge", /*6*/"Town Square - Civic Center", /*7*/"Across From Town Square", /*8*/"City Hall Offices", /*9*/"The Passage through City Hall", /*10*/"Town Square, Civic Center", /*11*/"City Hall Offices", /*12*/"Date Palm Dr South of Gerald Ford Dr", /*13*/"Date Palm Dr South of Vista Chino", /*14*/"Commercial Rd", /*15*/"E Palm Canyon Near Date Palm Dr", /*16*/"Pickfair Theatre", /*17*/"Cathedral Canyon Dr", /*18*/"Front Lawn of City Hall", /*19*/"Buddy Rogers Dr", /*20*/"Cathedral Canyon Dr at Dinah Shore", /*21*/"Dinah Shore Dr, East of Date Palm Dr", /*22*/"Ramon Rd at Date Palm Dr", /*23*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr", /*24*/"E Palm Canyon Dr", /*25*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr", /*26*/"Date Palm Dr at Perez Rd", /*27*/"Perez Rd Near Cathedral Canyon Dr", /*28*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr", /*29*/"San Jacinto Rd", /*30*/"Grove St Near E Palm Canyon Dr", /*31*/"Cathedral Canyon Drive at F Street", /*32*/"Grandview Ave", /*33*/"Cathedral Canyon Drive at F Street", /*34*/"Buddy Rogers Ave at Allen Ave", /*35*/"Da Val Dr at Century Park Dr", /*36*/"30th Ave at Santoro Dr", /*37*/"Officer David Vasquez Rd", /*38*/"Moreno Rd at Ocotillo Rd", /*39*/"Tachevah Dr at Avenida Maravilla", /*40*/"Dinah Shore Dr at Da Val Dr", /*41*/"Buddy Rogers Ave", /*42*/"Date Palm Dr at Buddy Rogers Ave"]

var cellImage = [/*0*/"arroyofront3.jpg", /*1*/"br1.jpg", /*2*/"chopsticksfront.jpg", /*3*/"colorfulfount.jpg", /*4*/"d1.jpg", /*5*/"DinahShore1b.jpg", /*6*/"f5.jpg", /*7*/"fount4.jpg", /*8*/"indianfront2.jpg", /*9*/"hol5a.jpg", /*10*/"h1.jpg", /*11*/"indiangatheringfront.jpg", /*12*/"IndianWomen2.jpg", /*13*/"cathedrals.jpg", /*14*/"fh1.jpg", /*15*/"pu10.jpg", /*16*/"lizard.jpg", /*17*/"cac2.jpg", /*18*/"swiss2.jpg", /*19*/"nb5.jpg", /*20*/"thunderfront.jpg", /*21*/"tictoc.jpg", /*22*/"wheelfront.jpg", /*23*/"artevitafront.jpg", /*24*/"coachella2.jpg", /*25*/"colinfisherfront.jpg", /*26*/"garyfront2.jpg", /*27*/"lesliefront.jpg", /*28*/"rebeccalogo2.jpg", /*29*/"adobefront.jpg", /*30*/"egfront.jpg", /*31*/"agnesfront.jpg", /*32*/"valfront.jpg", /*33*/"pricefront.jpg", /*34*/"dogparkfront.jpg", /*35*/"centuryfront.jpg", /*36*/"soccerparkfront.jpg", /*37*/"memorialfront.jpg", /*38*/"ocotillofront.jpg", /*39*/"panoramafront.jpg", /*40*/"patriotfront.jpg", /*41*/"townsquarefront.jpg", /*42*/"2ndfront.jpg"]

@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

struct Objects {
    var cellName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
    var detailObjects : [String]!
    var imageObjects : [String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchData()

    tableview.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    let radius = CLLocationDistance(160934) // 5 miles in meters

    objectsArray =
        [Objects(cellName: "Art",
            sectionObjects: [/*0*/"Arroyo", /*1*/"Buddy Rogers", /*2*/"Chopsticks", /*3*/"Colorful Fountain", /*4*/"Diamond", /*5*/"Dinah Shore Bridge Mosaics", /*6*/"Fountain of Life", /*7*/"Fountains", /*8*/"Historic Photo Collection", /*9*/"Holistic 77-A", /*10*/"Hollywood Heroes", /*11*/"Indian Gathering", /*12*/"Indian Women", /*13*/"Mountain Cathedrals", /*14*/"Old Firehouse", /*15*/"Perfect Union", /*16*/"Pickford Lizards", /*17*/"Saguaro and Barrell Cactus", /*18*/"Swiss Cheese", /*19*/"The New Beginning", /*20*/"Thunderbolt", /*21*/"Tic Toc", /*22*/"Wheel of Time"],
            detailObjects: [/*0*/"City Hall First Floor Lobby", /*1*/"Town Square - Civic Center", /*2*/"Da Val Dr at Ramon Rd", /*3*/"Cathedral City Branch Library", /*4*/"Patriot Park at Big League Dreams", /*5*/"Dinah Shore Bridge", /*6*/"Town Square - Civic Center", /*7*/"Across From Town Square", /*8*/"City Hall Offices", /*9*/"The Passage through City Hall", /*10*/"Town Square, Civic Center", /*11*/"City Hall Offices", /*12*/"Date Palm Dr South of Gerald Ford Dr", /*13*/"Date Palm Dr South of Vista Chino", /*14*/"Commercial Rd", /*15*/"E Palm Canyon Near Date Palm Dr", /*16*/"Pickfair Theatre", /*17*/"Cathedral Canyon Dr", /*18*/"Front Lawn of City Hall", /*19*/"Buddy Rogers Dr", /*20*/"Cathedral Canyon Dr at Dinah Shore", /*21*/"Dinah Shore Dr, East of Date Palm Dr", /*22*/"Ramon Rd at Date Palm Dr"],
            imageObjects: [/*0*/"arroyofront3.jpg", /*1*/"br1.jpg", /*2*/"chopsticksfront.jpg", /*3*/"colorfulfount.jpg", /*4*/"d1.jpg", /*5*/"DinahShore1b.jpg", /*6*/"f5.jpg", /*7*/"rf4.jpg", /*8*/"indianfront2.jpg", /*9*/"hol5a.jpg", /*10*/"h1.jpg", /*11*/"indiangatheringfront.jpg", /*12*/"IndianWomen2.jpg", /*13*/"cathedrals.jpg", /*14*/"fh1.jpg", /*15*/"pu10.jpg", /*16*/"lizard.jpg", /*17*/"cac2.jpg", /*18*/"swiss2.jpg", /*19*/"nb5.jpg", /*20*/"thunderfront.jpg", /*21*/"tictoc.jpg", /*22*/"wheelfront.jpg"]),
         Objects(cellName: "Art Galleries",
            sectionObjects: [/*23*/"Arte Vita Gallery", /*24*/"Coachella Valley Art Scene", /*25*/"Colin Fisher Studios", /*26*/"Gary's Creative Warehouse", /*27*/"Leslie Jean Porter Gallery", /*28*/"Rebecca Fine Art Gallery"],
            detailObjects: [/*23*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr", /*24*/"E Palm Canyon Dr", /*25*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr", /*26*/"Date Palm Dr at Perez Rd", /*27*/"Perez Rd Near Cathedral Canyon Dr", /*28*/"Perez Rd Near Date Palm Dr"],
            imageObjects: [/*23*/"artevitafront.jpg", /*24*/"coachella2.jpg", /*25*/"colinfisherfront.jpg", /*26*/"garyfront2.jpg", /*27*/"lesliefront.jpg", /*28*/"rebeccalogo2.jpg"]),
         Objects(cellName: "Historical Sites",
            sectionObjects: [/*29*/"Adobe House", /*30*/"El Gallito Restaurant", /*31*/"The Agnes Pelton Home", /*32*/"The Val Samuelson Home", /*33*/"Willard Price House"],
            detailObjects: [/*29*/"San Jacinto Rd", /*30*/"Grove St Near E Palm Canyon Dr", /*31*/"Cathedral Canyon Drive at F Street", /*32*/"Grandview Ave", /*33*/"Cathedral Canyon Drive at F Street"],
            imageObjects: [/*29*/"adobefront.jpg", /*30*/"egfront.jpg", /*31*/"agnesfront.jpg", /*32*/"valfront.jpg", /*33*/"pricefront.jpg"]),
         Objects(cellName: "Parks",
            sectionObjects: [/*34*/"Cathedral City Dog Park", /*35*/"Century Park", /*36*/"Dennis Keat Soccer Park", /*37*/"Memorial Park", /*38*/"Ocotillo Park", /*39*/"Panorama Park", /*40*/"Patriot Park", /*41*/"Town Square Park", /*42*/"2nd Street Park"],
            detailObjects: [/*34*/"Buddy Rogers Ave at Allen Ave", /*35*/"Da Val Dr at Century Park Dr", /*36*/"30th Ave at Santoro Dr", /*37*/"Officer David Vasquez Rd", /*38*/"Moreno Rd at Ocotillo Rd", /*39*/"Tachevah Dr at Avenida Maravilla", /*40*/"Dinah Shore Dr at Da Val Dr", /*41*/"Buddy Rogers Ave", /*42*/"Date Palm Dr at Buddy Rogers Ave"],
            imageObjects: [/*34*/"dogparkfront.jpg", /*35*/"centuryfront.jpg", /*36*/"soccerparkfront.jpg", /*37*/"memorialfront.jpg", /*38*/"ocotillofront.jpg", /*39*/"panoramafront.jpg", /*40*/"patriotfront.jpg", /*41*/"townsquarefront.jpg", /*42*/"2ndfront.jpg"])]

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    animateTable()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func animateTable() {
    tableview.reloadData()

    let cells = tableview.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableview.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
    }

    var index = 0

    for a in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            }, completion: nil)

        index += 1
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailForRegion region: CLRegion?, withError error: NSError) {
    print("Monitoring failed for region with identifier: \(region!.identifier)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Location Manager failed with the following error: \(error)")
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    //43
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectsArray[section].cellName
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 18)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArtCell") as UITableViewCell!)
    if (cell == cell) {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ArtCell")

        let imageName = UIImage(named: objectsArray[indexPath.section].imageObjects[indexPath.row])

        cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].detailObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = imageName
        cell.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)

        headerTitle.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        detailLabel.text = cellDetail[indexPath.row]
        centerImage.image = imageName
        backgroundImage.image = imageName


        //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        //let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        //let art = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        //cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.cellDetail[indexPath.row]
        //cell.imageView?.image = imageName
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)

        return cell
    }
    return cell

}

}
```

**Images:**

[image: viewcontroller in storyboard]

Comment: you have not set the tableView delegate or datasource to self?

Comment: You need to state your question clearly so we know how to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var headerTitle: UILabel!
```

So `headerTitle` is not something in your cell; it's just some outlet property of your CCArtController view controller. And you have never connected anything in your interface to that outlet, so it is `nil`. So when you try to set its `text`, you crash.

It seems likely that you're imagining that *every cell* has its own `headerTitle`. In that case, what you need here is a UITableViewCell subclass, with these `@IBOutlet` declarations there, and the elements of the cell hooked to them. You will then be able to set them by way of the cell.

Comment: I don't know what "work" even means. Your code makes no sense to me. Why on earth would you set the text of an outlet label every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called??? However, _that is not what you asked_. You asked why you're crashing, and I think I explained that. The way your code is written, there needs to be an actual UILabel at the other end of this outlet. Right now, there isn't one.

Comment: I don't think you really understand my question. Thanks for your input anyways.

Comment: If your question is faulty, edit it. You have not explained what you _think_ this `headerTitle` represents, but I have told you correctly what it _is_. I understand everything you actually said. I don't think you really understand my answer and my comment.

Comment: I have linked headerTitle to a label in my viewcontroller, but not in my tableview. How do I make it so that what I described above works?

Comment: If the label is in a cell of the table view, then there is a different label for every cell, yes? So this needs to be a property of a UITableViewCell subclass, not a UIViewController subclass.